# Kibana / ES / Lucene in ELK - group by message substring (without calculated field)

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

We've adopted centralized logging using the ELK stack. However, I'm at a loss on how to group messages based on substring (or regex or more complex processing) of their content.

Example:

- Message 1: deleted object id [123]
- Message 2: merged object id [123] to [456]
- Message 3: failed to merged object id [123] to [789]

and so on.

I would like to be able to group-by on messages answering a specific filter (e.g. *"failed to merge"*) but based on a regex (e.g. the first object id - "object id [(.*?)]" or something like that), so I would get a count of how many times object X failed to merge to any other object.

Is this possible with Kibana/ES/Lucene? Ideally I would like to do this through the Kibana UI, but I can almost just as easily use the query language. What I *can't* do is define calculated/scripted fields for each such query.

Comment: Can't you use Logstash? If you would parse the logs before indexing, you could create much more sophisticated queries.

Comment: @mottyg1 I'm actually using logstash, but I can't modify the indexed fields for every query. This is one aggregation variation out of 100's  that we want run.